# Recycler View on Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am making 50 data appear in my code, but I am putting it in a recycler view in a fragment because I have a dropdown menu, but when I put the code to call everything I get these two lines of error:

```
package com.example.tallerof.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.tallerof.R;
import com.example.tallerof.adapters.UsuariosAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    ArrayList<String> ListadeDatos;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Recycler1); /* Error #1 Cannot resolve method findViewById in GalleryFragment*/
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)); /* Error #2 required type: context provide: Gallery Fragment*/

    ListadeDatos=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<=50; i++){
        ListadeDatos.add("Dato # "+i+"");

    }

        UsuariosAdapter adapter= new UsuariosAdapter(ListadeDatos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must to do this.

```
recyclerView = getActivity().findViewbyId(R.id.Recycler1);
```

Regards.

Comment: In the line of  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)); I keep getting the "this" error, would I change it to getActivity?

Comment: Yes change, "this"  to "getActivity()"